Identify sci-fi movie (about terraforming ?)
I have never seen it, only saw ad on tv ... 5-6 or more years ago, so description will be very ambiguous.

there is one guy(alien) with pair of claws extending from bottom of jaw, yes claws and not teeth or tusks, although it resembles tusks, they grow
out from skin, i think he gets shot in the face by protagonist (?)
humans are fighting mutants described above on other planet (highly possible that planet is Mars)
Mutants are byproduct of terraforming (not sure)
short scene features futuristic hover tank that fires blue plasma (?) or it is rail gun (?), chassis of tank somewhat looks like train 

EDIT:

aliens are not green skinned they look like humans, mutated but still human, taller and with CLAWS on face, their skull is same as human, also featured alien in ad was bald 


Was the alien at all insectoid in nature?  Is it possible that these "claws" were in fact mandibles?

Longshot: Predator

Maybe "John Carter" (2012)?
The movie is set mostly on Mars, and some of the Martian creatures have some sort of claw/tusk whatever, see pictures below:


And here, futuristic ships firing blue plasma:

Trailer:



And here you can watch the movie:




surprisingly matching but its not it, i saw ad around 2008

its very probable john carter was inspired by that film

Then it is possibly Princess of Mars. This one is from 2009, and it is based on the same story as the 2012 "John Carter" movie.
In this movie, the Martian dude has a tusk (or whatever it is) as you can see in the picture below:
 
Trailer:



You can watch the complete movie here:




omg, still close but not it, i forgot to say that aliens are not really much different than humans expect taller starture and claws on face
